# p:datatable not showing updated value from session map

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using p:datatable to display value from list. I put this list in session map in one button click event. now i want to update this list from another jsf page which is open using javascript. after changing values I am getting updated list in controller but it is not updated in datatable. So if anyone have idea then please let me know. Here note that i am not using session bean only use session map to share the object with other jsf page.

Here is my code.. 
Controller1

```
@ViewScoped
@Controller
public class Controller1 implements Serializable {

private List<Object[]> dataList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

   public List<Object[]> getDataList () {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<Object[]> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    //on action  
    public String getRecords(){

    //retrieved from database    
    dataList=dataService.getData();

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
            sessionMap.put("data", dataList);
    return null;
    }

    public String openWindow(){
     //some logic
    return null;
    }
}
```

index.xhtml

```
    <p:commandButton id="buttonID" value="Populate Data"
    ajax="false"
    action="#{controller1.getRecords}"/>

<p:dataTable var="dataList1" id="dataListID"
    value="#{controller1.dataList}"
    rowIndexVar="index">

        <p:column headerText="Sr. No.">
                <h:outputText value="#{index + 1}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column
            headerText="Order No.">
            <h:outputText value="#{dataList1[0]}" />                                   
        </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton id="openButtonID" 
   action="#{controller1.openWindow}" value="Populate Data" 
   oncomplete="return windowPopup();"/>

<script>
    function windowPopup() {
    var windowPopup = null;
    windowPopup = window.open(
                    "index2.jsf?faces-redirect=true",
                    "ChildWindow",
    "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,width=1000,height=600");
    windowPopup.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Controller2

```
@ViewScoped
@Controller
public class Controller2 implements Serializable {

   private List<Object[]> itemList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

   public List<Object[]> getItemList () {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Object[]> itemList) {
        this.itemList= itemList;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Loggable
    public void init() {
       itemList = (List<Object[]>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("data");
    }

    public String processItem() {
      for (Object[] item: itemList) {
           item[0] = Integer.parseInt(item[0].toString())+1;
      }

      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext();
      Map<String, Object>   sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
            sessionMap.put("data", itemList);

      return null;
    } 
}
```

index2.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
action="#{controller2.processItem}"
/>
```

Now i close index2.xhtml. but i am not able to see updated value in p:datatable of index1.xhtml. I am able to see the values of itemList in index2.xhtml. I am also able to get updated value in Controller1.

Comment: Please read [ask] and act accordingly.

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry for inconvenience. I updated my question and also mention code.

Comment: Initialize the list `private List<Object[]> dataList` in its own place such as a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. There is no need to get hold of the list for the entire duration of the session. Since you are using PrimeFaces, you had better use [`LazyDataModel<T>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) with a bit learning curve in the beginning. And if something does not persist to the database, then it is not a JSF/PrimeFaces problem at all. It involves another layer which is completely invisible in the current post.

Comment: Since you are using Spring, those two beans are not view scoped beans as you are likely to believe. I do not want to repeat the same comment again and again over several places. Anyway, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444451/jsf-passing-paramater-through-link#comment47057233_29444451) it is in brief.

Comment: @Tiny thanks for solution. I found one way using LazyDataModel<T> to solve my problem. Thank you very much.